# Python Turtle or any other library for 2D drawing

Tags: python-3.x, python-turtle

I am using python3.7 and its math and turtle module
I have to draw a 2D sketch with arcs. For example

1. Draw a main circle with radius 1.5m
2. Draw another arc with radius of 1.7m and 2.8m from 5 degree to 75 degrees and join their end point
3. Now draw another circle at 5 degrees and at 2m from main circle with a radius of 0.4m.
4. Draw radial lines at interval of 10 degrees and write their respective angle at those radial lines.

Main circle can have radius as large as 10m. And all these values i can calculate with simple math lib of python. But to draw i thought i can use turtle module. But it draw in pixel with very limited values. Is there any way to scale these values to pixel in turtle module, or any other graphic library for this work.
Expected output is something like this.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nutn.png)

Comment: There is a way to do this with turtle, but first do you really want a "circle with radius 1.5m", that is a 1.5 meter radius?  It wouldn't show up on your screen!  Or is there some other scaling factor involved?  Or did you mean 1.5cm?

Comment: actually it really is 1.5m circle in drawing. I want a way to scale down all the dimensions without dividing by some value every time. In other word I want a method to treat my  400 X 400 pixel windows as  20 X 20m  canvas so that i can use my actual dimension.

Answer (score 0):

The Pillow library (PIL fork) can do it
https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Answer (score 0):

Use `setworldcoordinates()` to define your custom coordinate system:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

# I want a method to treat my 400 X 400 pixel window as
# a 20m X 20m canvas so that I can use my actual dimension

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(400, 400)
screen.setworldcoordinates(-10, -10, 10, 10)

turtle = Turtle()

# Draw a main circle with radius 1.5m

turtle.penup()
turtle.sety(-1.5)
turtle.pendown()
turtle.circle(1.5)

screen.exitonclick()
```